# Non singular matrices proof

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

The following problem is from an unknown book, if you know how the book is called, please tell me.

Let A be a non-singular matrix, $x$ and $y \in C^n$ . Show that:

[image: Problem 1]

Thank you, I don't know even how to start with this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a special case of the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity);
you can verify the first line directly by using the definition of an inverse.
\begin{align}
(A^{-1} + xy^*)\left(A - \frac{Axy^* A}{1+y^* Ax}\right)
&= I - \frac{xy^* A}{1+y^* Ax} + xy^*A - \frac{xy^* Axy^* A}{1+y^* Ax}\\
&= I + xy^* A - \frac{x(1 + y^* A x)y^* A}{1+y^* Ax}
\\
&= I + xy^* A - xy^* A\\
&= I.
\end{align}